# Add onkeyup event on datatable filter

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, datatable, onkeyup

I would like to add javascript event on this code:

```
<p:dataTable id="tblQueues" var="q" value="#{gateBacking.listQueue}" filteredValue="#{gateBacking.filteredQueues}" rowKey="#{q.queid}"  
     selection="#{gateBacking.selectedQueue}" selectionMode="single" widgetVar="varQueues"
     scrollable="true" scrollHeight="250">  
    ...
    <p:column headerText="License No" filterBy="#{q.fleet.licenseNo}" filterMatchMode="contains" >
        #{q.fleet.licenseNo}
    </p:column>
    ...
</p:dataTable>
```

How can I add `onkeyup` on the filter? I have tried like this:

```
<p:column headerText="License No" filterBy="#{q.fleet.licenseNo}" filterMatchMode="contains" onkeyup="formatLicense(this)">
```

but it doesn't work. How can I do that? Thanks.

---

**UPDATE**

I have tried this but it doesn't work:

```
<p:column headerText="License No" filterBy="#{q.fleet.licenseNo}" filterMatchMode="contains" filterEvent="formatLicense(this)">
```

---

**UPDATE 2**

```
<p:tabView id="tabViewGate">
    <p:tab id="tabCheckOut" title="Out">
        <h:form id="frmOut">
            <p:dataTable id="tblQueues" var="q" value="#{gateBacking.listQueue}" filteredValue="#{gateBacking.filteredQueues}" rowKey="#{q.queid}"  
                selection="#{gateBacking.selectedQueue}" selectionMode="single" widgetVar="varQueues"
                scrollable="true" scrollHeight="250">  
                ...
                <p:column id="colLicnu" headerText="License No" filterBy="#{q.fleet.licenseNo}" filterMatchMode="contains" >
                    #{q.fleet.licenseNo}
                </p:column>
                ...
            </p:dataTable> 

            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $("#frmOut\\:tblQueues\\:colLicnu\\:filter").keyup(function(){
                        //alert("Test"); //--> I tried this too but it doesn't work
                        if (input.value.length > 1)
                        {
                            var num = '1234567890';
                            var str = input.value[input.value.length-1];
                            var str2 = input.value[input.value.length-2];

                            if (num.indexOf(str) >= 0) {
                                if (!(num.indexOf(str2) >= 0)) 
                                    input.value = input.value.substring(0, input.value.length - 1) + " " + str;
                            }
                            else if (!(num.indexOf(str) >= 0)) {
                                if (num.indexOf(str2) >= 0)
                                    input.value = input.value.substring(0, input.value.length - 1) + " " + str;
                            }
                        }
                        input.value = input.value.replace("  "," ").toUpperCase();
                    });
                });
            </script>

        </h:form>
    </p:tab>
</p:tab>
```

Comment: What version of primefaces are you using ?

Comment: Thanks. I'll take another look.

Comment: @Andy: Btw I have tried `filterEvent="formatLicense(this)"` but it doesn't work..

Comment: @Andy: Ah sorry, my primefaces is 2.2, JSF is 2.0.2

Comment: I'm thinking you're just going to have to use straight js or Jquery to achieve what you want. The trouble is I'm trying to figure out how to call it. Sorry I'm too sleepy right now. If someone doesn't provide you an answer by then I'll take another swing at it.

Comment: Ok, sorry again. I will check up on this post first thing when I wake up.

Comment: @Andy: No need to sorry.. It's really helpful! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with some jQuery magic. I was using PrimeFaces 3.5 to determine this answer but you should be able to achieve the same thing on yours. The first thing you'll need to do is to determine the generated `id` for the `input` on the HTML side. You can do so by right clicking on the `input` (the one used to filter for that column) and choose View Source.

**Note**: I found it easier to simply add an `id` to `<h:form>`, `<dataTable>` and the `<p:column>` you're interested in (or you can do `prependId = "false"` on `<h:form>` to shorten it...whatever you wish). Then use this javascript (pseudocode) code .

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#inputTextId").keyup(function(){
    //logic goes here. 
  });
});
```

Here's a more concrete example. Below is a portion of my `<p:dataTable>`. I'm only showing the relevant parts. (Don't worry about the objects, I was playing with the PrimeFaces showcase).

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="car" value="#{carBean.cars}" widgetVar="carsTable">
        <p:column id="modelColumn" filterBy="#{car.model}" headerText="Model" filterMatchMode="contains">
            <h:outputText value="#{car.model}" />
        </p:column>
```

The generated id for the `input` was `form:dataTable:modelColumn:filter`

My javascript code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#form\\:dataTable\\:modelColumn\\:filter").keyup(function(){
    alert("Test"); 
  });
});
```

On my end this code was located under `resources/javascript/jscript.js`. So remember to add `<h:outputScript name="javascript/jscript.js" />` in `<h:head>`.

**UPDATE**

Whatever the `id` is for the `input` copy and paste **all** of it. Then escape the colons `:` with double backslashes. From your code given it should be

```
#tabViewGate\\:frmOut\\:tblQueues\\:colLicnu\\:filter
```

However, from your comments you're saying that the id is

```
A5290:tabViewGate:frmOut:tblQueues:colLicnu:filter
```

so it should be

```
#A5290\\:tabViewGate\\:frmOut\\:tblQueues\\:colLicnu\\:filter
```

Comment: Thank you, but I have tried that and it's the same. Pls see the updated question..

Comment: @mrjimoy_05 one sec. looking for a quick example.

Comment: @mrjimoy_05 oh no, this will not do. This is simply changing what event is triggered when filtering occurs. Instead of `keyup` you use `change`. Let me see what else I can find. You could use `JQuery` or JS directly.

Comment: Try this one and let me know how it turns out.

Comment: Hi Andy, thank you very much for the code. But I have tried your solution and it still doesn't work. I checked the ID in `inspect element` in Chrome, and I found: `A5290:tabViewGate:frmOut:tblQueues:colLicnu:filter`. So I tried to replace the ID on the javascript become this one, but caused the whole table can't filter or sorting. I have attached the full structure of my code on the Update 2 above. Please have a look. Thank you very much..

Comment: Whatever the id is for the input, copy and paste it and escape the `:` (colon) with `\\\` (double back slashes).

Comment: I updated my answer. Please let me know if it works now. We will figure this out.

Comment: @mrjimoy_05 Does it still not work for you ? I haven't check your actual javascript code because you said even `alert` was not even being called in your comments. It's working perfectly on my end, so please let me know.

Comment: @mrjimoy_05 Ok, let me get a closer look. Paste the entire page. If it's too big than use [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/) and send me the link via the comment. Even `alert` doesn't work ?